# Merge multiple list of dict with same value in common key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 4 list of dicts

```
list1 = [{'a':0,'b':23}, {'a':3,'b':77},{'a':1,'b':99}]

list2 = [{'a':1,'c':666},{'a':4,'c':546}]

list3 = [{'d':33,'a':3},{'d':1111,'a':4},{'d':76,'a':1},{'d':775,'a':0}]

list4 = [{'a':2,'e':12},{'a':4,'e':76}]
```

Every dict in the list has a common key 'a'. My requirement is 'a' key with same value in dict from all the list should be merged and if a particular key does not exist in the dicts while merging, then assign 0 for those keys or just omit those keys.
for eg. for key 'a' with value 1, from above example we have 2 dicts, one from list1 i.e {'a':0,'b':23} and one is list3, last dict i.e {'d':775,'a':0}, so 1st we have identified the dicts with same 'a' value, now need to merge these dicts
i.e {'a':0, 'b':23, 'c':0, 'd':775, 'e':0}, since both the dict didn't have 'c', 'c' is assigned as 0 here

I should get the output as:

```
[{'a':0,'b':23,'c':0,'d':775, 'e':0},{'a':1,'b':99,'c':666,'d':76,'e':0},{'a':2,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':12},{'a':3,'b':77,'c':0,'d':33,'e':0}, {'a':4,'b':0,'c':546,'d':1111,'e':76}]
```

usings minimum loops or list comprehension

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of how these four lists should be joined? A simple list of steps of the algorithm may be enough. Please also share any code with us that you have already tried.

Comment: all the list has a common key 'a' . 'a' key with same value  from all the list should be merged.

Comment: How should duplicate keys be treated, i.e. if `a==0` in two dictionaries and in both dictionaries the key `b` is present, which value should be kept. What have you tried so far?

Comment: duplicate keys wont come. all dicts are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more pythonic way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint
from collections import ChainMap

a = [{'a':0,'b':23}, {'a':3,'b':77}, {'a':1,'b':99}]
b = [{'a':1,'c':666}, {'a':4,'c':546}]
c = [{'d':33,'a':3}, {'d':1111,'a':4}, {'d':76,'a':1}, {'d':775,'a':0}]
d = [{'a':2,'e':12}, {'a':4,'e':76}]

dict_list = a + b + c + d

# You just need to specify the key you want to use in the lambda function
# There's no need to declare the different key values previously
res = map(lambda dict_tuple: dict(ChainMap(*dict_tuple[1])),
          groupby(sorted(dict_list,
                         key=lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["a"]),
                  key=lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["a"]))

pprint(list(res))
```

Outputs:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 23, 'd': 775},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 99, 'c': 666, 'd': 76},
 {'a': 2, 'e': 12},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 77, 'd': 33},
 {'a': 4, 'c': 546, 'd': 1111, 'e': 76}]
```

Edit (Improvement):

You can also use

```
from _operator import itemgetter
key=itemgetter("a")
```

instead of

```
key=lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["a"]
```

The version with itemgetter is much faster. Using the example you provided:

```
- Lambda: 0.037109375ms
- Itemgetter: 0.009033203125ms
```

Comment: I just added a performance improvement using itemgetter instead of lambdas.